# TypeScript module augmentation overwrites the original module?

Tags: typescript

In my Node.js / Express app, I've had Headers.ts file for quite a while with this content:

```
type HttpHeader = 'X-My-Header' | 'X-My-Other-Header' | 'X-Another';

declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
    import * as http from 'http';
    interface Request extends http.IncomingMessage, Express.Request {
        header(name: HttpHeader): string | undefined;
    }
}
```

It used to compile fine, however, after the recent `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install` again, I'm getting a lot of errors like

```
error TS2339: Property 'get' does not exist on type 'Request'.
error TS2339: Property 'end' does not exist on type 'Response'.
```

It seems that the core issue is that `node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts` resolves the `import * as core from "express-serve-static-core"` to my small augmentation and skips loading of the real thing entirely. I don't know why because I do have a folder `node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core` properly installed.

What could it be?

Comment: What typescript version are you using? The syntax you are using does not seem legal (you generally cannot have imports inside a module augmentation). Are you importing `express-serve-static-core` anywhere?

Comment: Some examples of how you are importing/using the `Request` type would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Judging from the:

```
import * as http from 'http';
```

inside of your module declaration, you are not, in fact writing a module "agumentation" like you want, but rather replacing the existing module.

In order to write a module augmentation you would need to write it as this:

```
import { Request} from 'express-serve-static-core';
import * as http from 'http';

export type HttpHeader = 'X-My-Header' | 'X-My-Other-Header' | 'X-Another';

declare module 'express-serve-static-core'{
    export interface Request extends http.IncomingMessage, Express.Request {
        header(name: HttpHeader): string | undefined;
    }
}
```

The first thing to note, is that it should me a external "file" module (it should have imports and exports).

The second thing to note is that the `import * as http` should go outside the module augmentation at is not legal inside.

The declared module now serves strictly as an augmentation. It will not over-write or replace the existing `express-server-static-core` module. In fact, that module is required to exist for it to be augmented (if you misspell the module name it would not compile' for example).

I cannot tell from your example why your code worked before. Perhaps there were differences in how `express-server-static-core` declaration files were implemented before. But if you follow this example, things should work for you.

Comment: Are you sure about the `import * as http`? TypeScript compiler even has an explicit message that I should try moving the import to outer scope (in some cases) so it kind of assumes that it is valid insider. This ambient declaration compiled fine before and also worked fine with module resolution.

Comment: Yes I'm positive. You are right, in a plain global ambient declaration it would work, but your problem is you should **not** be using a global ambient delcaration. What you are trying to do is **augment** a type within an existing module. `import` declarations are **not** allowed inside a module `augmentation` you will get a `TS2667: Imports are not permitted in module augmentations`.

Comment: I'm not even sure I'm doing the Request augmentation right, see e.g. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5bb102394148da1d481f2271cbde1b2bad330860/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L13. But that doesn't work for me either, I guess I'll create a separate question.

Comment: Oh it worked in a plan .ts file in my project. Previously, I (for some reason) tried to add it to `customtypes/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts` (I have `customtypes` registered as a type root in tsconfig.json) and it probably interfered with TypeScript's module resolution. However, I'm using this approach to augment some other modules like `async` and it seems to work fine. That's probably what confused me.

Comment: Where would you recommend storing this module augmentation?

Comment: You can put it in a `.d.ts` file somewhere in your project (I have a `custom-typings/` folder I use for that purpose. Remember though, since this is now a `module` it won't be automatically included, you have to `import 'custom-typings/my-typing.d.ts'` somewhere in your project for the augmentation to become available.

Comment: Hm, it doesn't work in a sense that the IDE does not see references to my new method overload. It compiles fine but kind of beats the purpose.

Comment: It should see the change, but your change is subtle so it would be hard to see it. The problem is that it will not remove the old overload so any string is still acceptable and you won't get completion for the header names. For example if you returned a different type like `:number` from your overload then the ide should let you know the result is number when using one of your literal header types.  But in your case, it won't be much help.

Comment: You're right, as soon as I make some drastic change like changing the return type, compilation errors are all over the place. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: BTW, the new module does not need to imported anywhere. Still seems to work fine.