# How can I extend type definition of existing npm modules?

Tags: typescript, recharts

I'm using recharts for making charts in my react webapp. 
In 'XAxis' component of recharts, there is optional prop 'tickMargin' but type definition included in npm package didn't define this prop. So I tried to add this prop by making custom type definition file(d.ts).

#### Original Definition

```
// {project_folder}/node_modules/recharts/types/cartesian/XAxis.d.ts
export interface Props extends BaseAxisProps {
    // some definitions...
}
```

#### My d.ts

```
// {project_folder}/@types/recharts/index.d.ts
declare module "recharts" {
  interface BaseAxisProps {
    tickMargin?: number
  }
}
```

#### page.tsx

```
import {XAxis} from "recharts"

<XAxis tickMargin={3} />
```

But then, TS compiler says `error TS2305: Module '"recharts"' has no exported member 'XAxis'.` and for all other recharts components. It seems my custom type definition completely replaced exisitng definition. I googled many times but I still don't know how to solve this behavior. How can I extend type definition not replacing it? 

Below is my tsconfig.json for reference.

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "ES6"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "outDir": "./tsc/",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "/*": ["./*", "./@types/*"],
      "recharts": ["/node_modules/recharts/types/*", "/@types/recharts/*"]
    },
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456231/typescript-module-augmentation-overwrites-the-original-module You have to make your file a module importing the module you want to augment, otherwise it is a declaration, not an augmentation.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you so much! It works perfect!! I didn't know the exact word 'augmentation'...

Answer (score 1):

For anyone landing here with a similar issue and using the built-in recharts library type definitions instead of DT.

**/src/custom_typings/recharts/index.d.ts**

```
import * as recharts from 'recharts/types/util/types';

declare module 'recharts/types/util/types' {
  export interface BaseAxisProps {
    tickMargin?: number;
  }
}
```

I didn't have to specifically import that file or reference it in `tsconfig.json`.